# Is there is a time-limit to speech recognition while using Web Speech API?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webspeech-api, transcription, time-limiting

I am working on a project that involves speech recognition as an intermediate step but I am facing an issue in transcription. I am using Web Speech API and running my application on Chrome. The transcription prints for a while but stops after a certain time so I wanted to know if there is a time-limit to recognition via Web Speech API? What I want to achieve is that the transcription stops only when I have stopped it manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.